Any way to wrap string line in pinescript?
I´m trying to wrap one very long string, and I can´t find a way in the documentation.
pc_entry_alertPips(direction_entry, slPips, tpPips, betrigger, atrtrigger) => 
    
pc_id + "," + direction_entry + "," + pc_symbol + "," + "risk=" + str.tostring(pc_risk) + "," + "sl=" + str.tostring(slPips) + "," + "tp=" + str.tostring(tpPips) + "," + "spread=" + str.tostring(pc_spread) + "," + "betrigger=" + str.tostring(betrigger) + "," + "beoffset=" + str.tostring(pc_betriggerOffset) + "," + "atrperiod=" + str.tostring(pc_atrperiod) + "," + "atrmultiplier=" + str.tostring(pc_atrmultiplier) + "," + "atrtrigger=" + str.tostring(atrtrigger)

Any idea?

What version of pinescript are you using?

I use v5, I know that it works in 1 line of code, but I was trying to make it easier to read with several shorter lines
